# NSTextField and Opt+Enter etc for forcing multiple lines - A bug or Feature?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

While developing an application, I am asked to remove multi-line text inputs from `NSTextField` - Which I did.

Again they said users are able to paste multiline texts, then I disabled <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

From here...
I have a confusion... Why NSTextField allows <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and other key shortcuts (like hacking) to insert a new line character. I read somewhere that it is a feature not a bug, but I am unable to find that link.

Is the above correct, and is it mentioned any where in Apple Documentation?

Comment: What is your current solution for blocking multline text?

Comment: @HampusNilsson: you can find dozen of answers...in SO

Comment: Yes there are many answers already. I'd like to help you but you could delimit the work of finding a method that works by saying which methods do not work. :)

Comment: @HampusNilsson: I am not asking for any codes. My question is "Is ctrl+enter a bug or feature as it inserts a new line." If it is a feature then is it documented somewhere so that I can give reference.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is documented (or at least mentioned as a feature of NSTextField) here in the Mac developer library: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1454/_index.html

Comment: Thanks Hampus.... +1 for helping me.... and I will wait for others answers.... before accepting yours... sorry for this.

Comment: My fault, I should have been more diligent in reading your question. :) Walker's answers is the better one as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another doc reference: [Working with the Field Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW29).  Specifically, it says "Users can easily put newline characters into a text field by pressing Option-Return or Option-Enter."